# How to optimize number of sql queries of get_option()?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$name = get_option('name');
$phone = get_option('phone');
$street = get_option('street');
$postal_code = get_option('postal_code');
$email = get_option('email');
```

It will run 5 additional queries. Is it possible to minimize to 1?

Comment: write a new function to get multiple options at once `get_options(['name', 'phone', 'yadayada'])`

Answer (score 2):

This will improve performance

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT `option_name`,`option_value` FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` in('name', 'phone', 'street', 'postal_code', 'email')";
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, OBJECT_K );

//access option values, ex: name
var_dump($result['name']->option_value);
```

Answer (score 1):

These probably aren't separate queries in most cases options are loaded to a global at page load, the get_option function loads off the global before running a query.

If you have custom options you can also add those to the global by setting the autoload to 'yes' when you update the option.

[Codex: update_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wp_load_alloptions()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_load_alloptions/).